# Does mod_auth_openidc support STS(Security Token Service)?

Tags: token, sts-securitytokenservice, mod-auth-openidc

Since mod_auth_openidc is an authentication/authorization module for the Apache 2.x HTTP server that authenticates users against an OpenID Connect Provider. If OpenID Connect Provider supports STS(Security Token Service) does mod_auth_openidc is supported for that.I couldn't find any resources which explains about this.

Answer (score 0):

No, assuming you refer to the WS-Trust STS.

Update: there's a separate module https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_sts that supports various token exchange protocols including WS-Trust.